# Q&A - How to force device orientation to rotate between landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

> *I'm posting this in [Q&A style](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305794/how-to-deal-with-downvotes-on-self-answered-questions) as there are currently a few posts on*
>   *S/O with similar questions and answers that aren't perfectly correct*
>   *for all use cases. They typically suffice OP's one specific use case*
>   *but are bad for people coming to the site searching for a general-use*
>   *answer and lead to hours of frustrated debugging, as I just*
>   *experienced. (And in doing so scourged through all of StackOverflow's*
>   *resources to find that this question (and its answer) had not been*
>   *officially asked anywhere except in comments on other posts).*

---

## Q: How can I force my app to toggle between portrait and landscape mode at will?

While there are many tiny snippets that allow for it they fail in various unforseen ways.

For example:

1) You can rotate the screen UI (not device orientation) but then if you screenshot or show iOS native things like pop up alerts they will be oriented the wrong way.

2) If you set the `orientation` key to your desired orientation UI doesn't always auto-update immediately after (or at all).

3) If you just manually do that and manually update UI, other VCs may still tamper w/ orientation, it's not 'locked in'.

4) If you manually update device orientation and refresh UI, adding a new ViewController.view will have the width and height flipped as the device settings haven't updated yet even though UI has, you have to wait an unknown amount of time (between 0 and 1 seconds) for the rotation animation to finish before these properties (UIDevice's dimensions) are updated.

Etc.

My answer below addresses all potential issues as found while searching through various SO threads.

Comment: It's fine to post your own question and answer but the question still needs to be a valid question that follows all of the rules allowing for anyone to post an answer. Currently this question is no where close to being appropriate for SO. Please post a full question showing all of the normal effort expected in a question.

Comment: @rmaddy Respectfully, I'm not sure what else to add. There is no simple way to force change orientation in iOS at any time. The question is very straight forward, 'how do I do that'.

Comment: @rmaddy I've tried adding an explanation as to why this QA is necessary, hope that suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A:

Add to AppDelegate.h

```
@property () BOOL landscape;
```

Add to AppDelegate.m

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    if (self.landscape) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}


-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    if (self.landscape) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (self.landscape) {
        return (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    } else {
        return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (self.landscape) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

Add to your VC.m

```
-(void)setLandscape:(BOOL)landscape {
    
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.landscape = landscape;
    
    if (landscape) {
        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
    } else {
        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
    }
    
    [UINavigationController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];//THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT LINE IN HERE AND EVERYONE AND ALL SAMPLE CODE LEAVES IT OUT FOR SOME REASON, DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE. (Forces UI to update), otherwise this orientation change will randomly fail around 1% of the time as UI doesn't refresh for various unknown reasons.
    
}
```

The most important line is `[UINavigationController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];` which for some reason everyone all across the web, stackoverflow, sample code, etc leaves out. Just setting the `orientation` key will cause this to work 98% of the time, but randomly UI won't update or it will update before key is set and you get an orientation bug, this forces it to update when you need it to.